# Debian on HP ProLiant server hangs (disk i/o is my guess)

Tags: debian, zfs, debian-squeeze

I installed Debian (2.6.32-5-amd64) on my HP ProLiant MicroServer (purchased recently.) I also added 3 2tb hd in zfs. I've experienced several server froze. Sometimes it showed Soft lockup CUP stuck for 61s! Today I experienced a different problem (I think) and the message looked like this

```
[431336.200002] Call Trace:
[431336.200002]  [<ffffffff812fcc7c>] ? _write_lock+0xe/0xf
[431336.200002]  [<ffffffff810d7a86>] ? __vmalloc_node+0x99/0xe2
:
:
```

and (in different screen)

```
[431354.222318] Node 0 DMA32 free: 2064kB min:5520kB low:69900kB high:8280kB active_anon:181648kB inactive_anon:61728kB active_file:313152kB inactive_file:832456kB unevictable: 0kB isolated(anon): 0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1922596kB mlocked:0kB dirty:72kB writeback:0kB mapped:25620kB shmem:344kB slab_reclaimable:34460kB slab_unreclaimable:31400kB kernel_stack:2288kB pagetables:7556kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
[431354.222431] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
:
:
```

Is this a hardware problem? What tools/methods can I find out the source of the problem? I've used Debian for years but never had problem like this.

Comment: It seems like it had something to do with transmission-daemon, according to [this post.](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/8043)

Comment: How do you have ZFS installed?

Comment: Downloaded the source (SPL and ZFS) and followed the instructions from [ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/)

Comment: In that case, can you post the full call trace so we can see if it came from zfs?

Answer (score 1):

The *Node 0 DMA32 free* line is part the message written by [Linux's Out Of Memory (OOM) killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM). It shows that you used more memory than you had RAM and swap space.

Comment: BTW: ZFS neds loads of memory, especially with deduplication enabled.